# Django + opcua, background gateway

Tags: django, linux, web-services, opc-ua

I am currently updating a web application based on Django framework.

Im currently building a new json RestApi to manage our remote station.

Our current api use Modbus tcp to talk with plc controller but for improving the security we want to switch to OPC-UA.

I did few test and the solution is clearly functional but here is the problem:

Django execute code in view once and then return the result.

We need to open a session, browser to the node and get the value and before returning the result, we should close the session. That is take huge amount of Time.

Usually OPC-UA keep session active as long as the connection between both device exist.

I need to have an service or something similar that act as a gateway for django where django just request node data and the gateway manage to keep connection with device and fill django request.

Any idea? Mais

Comment: Actually, I did a python script as service that run in background, subscribe to UPCUA server, and on update, he populate a MYSQL Datatable.